# Does Kotlin supports Dialogflow?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogflow-es

As from the [official site reference](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks), dialogflow has no listing of kotlin but i can see third party implementations in various github repositories. Is it ok that i can start using those references or google team has any future plans for kotlin?

Inputs will be helpful to proceed further on implementing chatbot in kotlin based android application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's Java library available and You can use it without problem thanks to Kotlin/Java interop. That's probably what all those third party implementations do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as there is a Java library.

Kotlin is made to be fully interoperable with Java.